# why isn't nlog saving a bad request url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nlog

I use ASP.NET Core and NLog.Web.AspNetCore (4.3.1). NLog isn't saving a bad request url - why?
That is mine NLog.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/nlog.txt"
            layout="${longdate} url: ${aspnet-request-url} | ${message}"/>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="logfile"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

When I have a 404 error nlog is saving:

> 2017-05-11 20:07:34.2466 url:  | My error message

**Url above is empty - why?**

My Configure method in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            // .....

            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/ApplicationError");
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/Error/{0}");

            // .....

            loggerFactory.AddNLog();
            app.AddNLogWeb();

            // ......
        }
```

My Error controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<ErrorController> _logger;

    public ErrorController(ILogger<ErrorController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult ApplicationError()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("/Error/Error/{statusCode}")]
    public IActionResult Error(int statusCode)
    {
        _logger.LogError("My error message");

        return View(statusCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your application have a Nuget reference to `NLog.Web`?  The `aspnet-request-url` layout renderer isn't part of NLog itself.

Comment: I have NLog.Web.AspNetCore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the AspnetCore extensions to your NLog configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    </extensions>

    ...
</nlog>
```

See [the NLog AspnetCore documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-(csproj---vs2017)) for more info.

Comment: Splendid! I'm happy to have helped.